# An explicit calculation of Galois group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, galois-theory

This is a question requires to compute the Galois group of $X^4+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$,  $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, $\mathbb{F}_3$ and $\mathbb{F}_5$.

Here is a brief of what I can think of.

For the first two, the splitting field is $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$. Since $X^2+1$ and $X^2-2$ are irreducible, the Galois group should be $C_2 \times C_2$ and $C_2$.

I am not sure what happens when the field is finite.

=================================

I thought about the first case again last night but I messed up myself a little bit. Take $\zeta_8 = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}i$ to be the eighth partition of unity. The splitting field of $X^4+1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ should be $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)$, since $\zeta_8$ generates other roots which are $\zeta_8^3,\zeta_8^5, \zeta_8^7$. It follows $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_8)/\mathbb{Q})=Aut(C_8)=C_4$.

On the other hand, $\zeta_8$ and $\zeta_8^3$ generates $\sqrt{2}$ and $i$, which leads to the answer I tried to gave last time. In this case, the Galois group seems to be $C_2 \times C_2$.

For sure the degree of extension is $4$, but I cannot figure out which approach is correct.

Comment: When the field is finite, the Galois group is generated by the Frobenius map (exercise), and the only thing to calculate is its order.

Comment: In the case of finite fields the factorization (and hence also the splitting field) of this polynomial has been studied [in this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/77161/11619). The order of the Galois group then follows as in Qiaochu's comment.

Comment: I don't see how "It follows ... $C_4$." Each automorphism $\sigma$ taking $\zeta$ to $\zeta^j$ has $\sigma^2=1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks for the reminder, I got the correct computation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Over $F_3$ you have $\sqrt{2} = \sqrt{-1} = i$, so the extension is quadratic.
Over $F_5$, you have $i = \sqrt{-1} = \sqrt{4} = \pm 2$, so again the extension is quadratic.
Since extensions of finite fields are always cyclic, this was to be expected.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to see what's going on:

The quadratic extension of ${\bf F}_3$ has 9 elements, so its multiplicative group has 8 elements, but the multiplicative group of a finite field is always cyclic, so there's an element $a$ with order 8; then $a$ is a zero of $x^8-1=(x^4-1)(x^4+1)$ but not of $x^4-1$, hence of $x^4+1$.

Similarly for the quadratic extension of ${\bf F}_5$ and its multiplicative group, cyclic of order 24, which number is a multiple of 8.

Comment: I understood the part in this approach which gives a root of $x^4+1$ in the quadratic extension of $F_3$. How can we see the polynomial split in the extension?

Comment: I should have noted that there are 4 elements of order 8 in the cyclic group of order 8, so 4 roots of $x^4+1$, so it splits.