# If $q(X)$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$, then it's reducible in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ for every prime $p$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, prime-numbers, irreducible-polynomials

My book states, without a proof, that

> If $q(X)$ is reducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$, then it's reducible in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$ for every prime $p$.

The contrapositive of the above result is more useful: if one finds a prime $p$ such that $q(X)$ is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$, then it's irreducible in $\mathbb Z[X]$.

I was wondering how one might prove the result, but then read this question:
[Irreducible polynomial which is reducible modulo every prime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77155/irreducible-polynomial-which-is-reducible-modulo-every-prime),
which seems to be in contrast with the above statement. How is that possible?

Comment: I would quibble with this statement in the case that $q(X)$ is not monic.  It's a matter of semantics whether one considers $5X^2+6X+1$ to be reducible in $\mathbb Z_5[X]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following implication is true (as you mention):
$$q(X) \in \Bbb Z[X] \text{ monic reducible } \implies \bar q(X) \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z[X] \text{ reducible for all prime } p$$
The contrapositive of this implication is:
$$\bar q(X) \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z[X] \text{ irreducible for some prime } p \implies q(X) \in \Bbb Z[X] \text{ irreducible (or non monic) }$$

However, the implication
$$q(X) \in \Bbb Z[X] \text{ irreducible monic } \implies \bar q(X) \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z[X] \text{ irreducible for some prime } p$$

is the *converse* of the first implication, which doesn't hold in general (as you provide a link to give a counter-example).

---

The first implication can be proven as follows:
if you assume $q= fg$ with $f,g \in \Bbb Z[X] \setminus \{±1\}$, then $\bar q = \bar f \bar g \in \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z[X]$. If you suppose that the dominant coefficient of $q$ is not a multiple of $p$ (e.g. $q$ monic), then both $\bar f$ and  $\bar g$ have positive degree, hence $\bar q $ is reducible.

---

More generally, if $A$ is a UFD, $a \in A$ is an element, $f \in A[X]$ is a polynomial with content $1$ and with dominant coefficient invertible in $A/(a)$, then the irreducibility of $\bar f$ in $A/(a)[X]$ gives the irreducibility of $f$ in $A[X]$. [Berhuy, theorem IV.2.3].

Comment: Ah, I see where I went wrong, thanks for pointing out the difference between the contrapositive and the converse. I still don't understand why $p$ has to be prime though. If $a,b,c \in \mathbb Z$ and $a = bc$, then it's true that $\bar a = \bar b \bar c$ in $\mathbb Z_n$ even if $n$ is not prime. What am I missing?

Comment: @rubik : you are right. However, we look at $\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ when $p$ is prime because it is a field, while $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ is not a field (it's not even an integral domain) if $n$ is composite.

Comment: Ok, that's clear, thanks. But the important thing here is that the coefficients are in a PID (like $\mathbb Z$), not necessarily in a field, right?

Comment: Yes, you can even generalize to [UFD's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unique_factorization_domain). A PID is always a UFD. I will correct the end of my answer, since we can pick an element $p$ in our UFD $A$ even if it is not irreducible in $A$. So in our case, we can consider $\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z$ even if $n$ is not prime (in $A=\Bbb Z$), if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

**The idea of the proof**

Suppose $q(X)$ reducible over $\mathbb Z[X]$. Then, $$q(X)=R(X)P(X)$$
where $\deg q,\deg R>0$. In particular, in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$, $$\bar q(X)=\bar R(X)\bar P(X).$$

Now, you have to manage with primitive polynomials, since in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$, some polynomial can be null (that is not possible with primitive roots) (for example $2X^2+2$ in $\mathbb Z_2[X]$. Be careful, since $2$ is not a unit in $\mathbb Z$, you have that $2X^2+2$ is a reducible over $\mathbb Z$).