# Is $x^4+1$ irreducible in $F_3[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Is $x^4+1$ irreducible in $F_3[x]$?

I don't know any irreducibility criteria over $F_p[x]$ - so I tried to decompose it using $1=-2-3n\pmod 3$ and make $2+3n = p^2$ so that $x^4+1$ turns into $x^4-p^2$ - but didn't succeed.

Comment: Easy to see there are no roots.  Try to factor it as the product of two quadratics.

Comment: Background information: over $\Bbb R$ it is $(x^2+\sqrt{2}x+1)(x^2-\sqrt{2}x+1)$. There is no square root of $2$ in $\Bbb F_3$, which suggests the answer should be no. One obtains this factorization by writing it as a product of quadratics and proceeding, which is how you'll get a contradiction here

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77155/11619).

Comment: $x^4+1 = x^4+4\,$ factors by completing the square, as in the linked dupe (put $\,k=1\,$ there). $\ \ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. One reason is that you can use a nice factorization of $a^4+4b^4$ usually seen in mathematical competitions (eg here https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Sophie_Germain_Identity). This is relevant in your case because $x^4+1=x^4+4$ in your field.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** If $X^4+1$ would be reducible, it would either be the product of a first degree and a cubic, or of two quadratics.

The first case happens if and only if $X^4+1$ has a root in $\mathbb F_3$, which is easy to check.

In the second case
$$X^4+1=(X^2+aX+b)(X^2+cX+d)$$

Now open the brackets and solve.