# Factoring polynomials into prime prime polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

How can I factorize $$p(x)=x^4+1 \in \mathbb{Z_5}$$ and $$p(x)=x^4+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3$$ into prime polynomials?

Is $(x^2+2)(x^2+3)$ correct for $\mathbb{Z}_5$? Because $2 \cdot3 = 1$ and $2+3 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.

And how is it done for $\mathbb{Z}_3$?

Comment: Your answer for $\mathbb{Z}_{5}$ seems correct, now just do the same for $\mathbb{Z}_{3}$.

Comment: [A generalization](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77155/11619). Do notice that modulo a prime $\equiv1\pmod8$ this polynomial factors into a product of four linear polynomials.

Answer (score 1):

Note that  your factorisation in $\mathbf Z_5$ may as well be written as 
$$x^4+1=(x^2+2)(x^2-2),$$
which makes it more obvious.

**Hint for** $\mathbf Z_3$:
$$ x^4+1=(x^2-1)^2+2x^2=(x^2-1)^2-x^2. $$

Comment: Even more clearly: $x^4+1=x^4-4=(x^2+2)(x^2-2)$.

Comment: That's what I meant, but I started from the O.P.'s factorisation.

Comment: @Bernard For $\mathbb{Z}_3$ I ended up with $(x^2+x-1)(x^2-x-1)$. Is that correct?

Comment: Absolutely correct. You can check performing the multiplication anyway.