# Is $\langle x⁴+1\rangle$ maximal in $\Bbb Z_7[x]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think if I show that $x^4+1$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z_7[x] $, then  is maximal in $\Bbb Z_{7}[x]$, but please assure me.

Comment: Since $Z / 7Z$ is a field, you can indeed try show that the polynomial $x^4+1$ is irreducible to get that $(x^4+1)$ is maximal.

Comment: try to factor $x^4+1$ into a product of quadratic polynomials

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/77155/11619) for a generalization. That polynomial is **not** irreducible modulo any prime. May be I should vote to close this as a duplicate?