# Incorrect Solution for A Book of Abstract Algebra Chapter 26 Question E4

Tags: abstract-algebra, irreducible-polynomials

For this exercise, you are supposed to show that the polynomial
$$
x^4+1
$$
is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}_5$.
However, I found that
$$
(x^2+2)(x^2+3) = x^4+5x^2+6
               = x^4+1.
$$

Is the question wrong or am I?

Book citation: Pinter, Charles C. "A book of abstract algebra. Reprint of the second (1990) edition." (2010).

Comment: No, I'm pretty sure that $(x^2+2)(x^2+3)$ would be equal to $x^4\color{red}{+5x^2+6}$ and not $x^4+1$. Would you please show how you got that $(x^2+2)(x^2+3)=x^4+1$?

Comment: @CrSb0001 The OP is doing this over $\mathbb Z_5$

Comment: @0XLR Ah sorry, I must have been thinking of a different set there :\

Comment: Well, we can't argue with direct computations. This equality shows the polynomial is reducible over $\mathbb{Z_5}$.

Comment: @Mark  That's about what I thought but it seemed too simple a problem to not only be wrong but I believe you are also meant to use this to prove a part of a later question in the chapter which makes it worse somehow.

Comment: In fact, $x^4 + 1$ is 'famous' for beeing reducible over every finite field, but irreducible over $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: Yes, there are many sources proving that $x^4 + 1$ is reducible over finite fields check [Wikipedia itelf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Example) and examples on this site e.g.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/77155/irreducible-polynomial-which-is-reducible-modulo-every-prime

Comment: This seems to be an instance of the common student error that a polynomial with no root must be irreducible. By the way, write $+1=-4$, and the factorization is obvious.